# (Python) Process Launcher for development purposes

Tags: python, process, development-environment

For a distributed system I have several processes that are required to be launched and I am working on (developing) almost all of them at the same time (modify here, adapt there, ...).

I usually run them in several terminal windows, but would prefer some kind of "process launcher" where I can configure the individual processes in a config file, and then preferrably get the log output, maybe colorized, in a single terminal window.

I started to write something on my own, but have not been happy with the result and wonder if there is not a dedicated tool for that purpose.

Reloading (on file change) would be cool, but I could also use `watchmedo` for that purpose.

Does someone here have a hint for me?

Comment: what system do you means? Linux often `systemd` to start processes. You can also use [supervisord](https://supervisord.org) to run processes and it should automatically restart them it they are killed. This method is often used with web services created with Flask or Django.

Answer (score 1):

You might find that a project called process-compose does the things you need, if you are specifically avoiding containers and docker-compose.

https://github.com/F1bonacc1/process-compose

I believe it meets all the criteria you mentioned plus quite a bit more.

Specifically to your needs it provides:

- process launch management
- multi-process dependency management
- unified/combined logging

I’m not sure if there is a built-in for reload on file-modified, but I expect you could achieve that with a bit of config or code glue.

I particularly like the formal config-driven liveness and readiness checks for processes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), using it you will be able to predefine multiple python processes easily and run them all together, seeing the logs of each process live and colored, restarting all or part of them, etc...